# Error with find new pending eth transaction web3.py

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I'm trying to find new transactions (maybe not yet added to the blockchain) from a certain address

here's how i'm trying to do it with web3.py library and async

```
import asyncio

from web3 import Web3

ADDR = 'MY_ETH_ADDRES'


async def watch(w3, address):


    options = {
    'fromBlock': 'pending',
    'toBlock': 'latest',
    'address': address,
  }

  tx_filter = w3.eth.filter(options)

  for event in tx_filter.get_new_entries():
      print(event)

  await asyncio.sleep(2)


def main():
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('eth node here'))

  try:
    loop.run_until_complete(
      watch(w3, ADDR)
    )
  finally:
    loop.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It doesn't work because it shows me this error:

> invalid from and to block combination: from > to

**UPD**: full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\carlos\PycharmProjects\testeth\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\carlos\PycharmProjects\testeth\main.py", line 26, in main
    loop.run_until_complete(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\carlos\PycharmProjects\testeth\src\address.py", line 44, in watch
    tx_filter = self.web3.eth.filter(options)
  File "C:\Users\carlos\PycharmProjects\testeth\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str, params, error_formatters)
  File "C:\Users\carlos\PycharmProjects\testeth\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 158, in request_blocking
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'invalid from and to block combination: from > to'}
```

Comment: could you add the whole stacktrace. the error without context isn't very helpful

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if error shows problem `from > to` then it can meas that `pending > latest`

Comment: I added a full stacktrace. latest - these are the last blocks, apparently among them should be my block with the transaction.
I tried to remove latest but it did not work

Comment: did you try to replace values `'fromBlock': 'latest', 'toBlock': 'pending',` Maybe blockchain has to work in different direction.

Comment: Yes, maybe I was wrong! But now I'm not so sure that my asynchronous code is written correctly. Because at the moment the program doesn't output anything....

Comment: Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: do you have any documentation for this module? are there any examples? Did you try to use them before you created own code?

Comment: yeah! its code like here (a bit modifided fro my task) https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html